# Deploying Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I've developed a small MVC project using Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL, Maven and Tomcat. I can run and test the application (locally) smoothly.

Now I need to publish/deploy this project on an (online) server that have only Tomcat installed on it. How can I publish/deploy the project online? Is there any special build I should do? What files I shall upload and to where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several types of development options available.

For development on localhost EAR (Exploded ARchive) type of project is usually used (because you can easily make hot deploy on servery). But for production WAR (Web ARchive) is used (basically it's the same EAR archive, but compressed using ZIP algorithm).

If you want to deploy your project to remote Tomcat server then make your project as WAR archive and upload it to Tomcat's webapps directory. Then you might need to restart Tomcat. But it's manual way of deploying.

Better option is to use automated build tools (like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)) which can compile your project, run unit tests, deploy on web server (local or remote) etc.

This one is a great example of how to deploy your project on Tomcat server by using Maven's **tomcat-maven-plugin**: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do a mvn clean install and you will get a .war file in your target directory of web module.
Copy it and paste it in tomcat_home/webapps directory and restart tomcat. Thats it. now, you can access it in whatever configured port (eg: `http://localhost:8080/<your webapp war name>`). lets say your war name is myapp.war, then tomcat would have extracted it into myapp folder in webapps.
so your url will be  `http://localhost:8080/myapp`

Comment: Why not do `mvn clean package` instead of `install`?

Comment: It can also be done, as package phase is included in install, i said that and both will work

Comment: As `install` does more then just package the application it's not the preferred method. Unless you wan't to be able to include this web application into other projects as a dependency.

Comment: I think, the OP, wanted to ask how to deploy it online (to be accessed through internet) not locally like you have answered.

Answer (score 0):

With maven deploy command, usually gets errors for various reasons. 
if you work in Unix/Linux system, I recommend using "rsync" method on console. (You can write own shell script to manage easily). It helps not only deploying without a problem but also helps to get time while redeploying (only uploading changed / new files). Because maven deploy / redeploy uploads your project as a bundle in jar/war. However "rysnc" method uploads your project files one by one.

Before using it, you should sure that two conditions.

1- your project is built in target folder (Spring Tool Suite)

2- you have access to tomcat via ssh

**example code :** *(v_ : prefix which is variable(customizable))*

```
rsync -avz v_your_project_in_target root@v_ip:v_tomcat_name/webapps/v_project_name
```

(Second sharing)